# JFrame ContentPane listener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, listener, contentpane

Is there some kind of listener (and which will be the best to use) which triggers after the content pane of a `JFrame` is set?

So every time I call `myJFrameClass.setContentPane(someJPanel)` it will start doing some stuff?

I was wondering about `ContainerListener` or `AncestorListener`? but I'm really not sure about what should I use.

Comment: Try both and see what you get

Comment: Create a `setContentPaneAndDoSomeStuff` method and only call that. Or extend frame and override `setContentPane` to do the same.